# model update method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model

for example, I have a table 'post' and column 'views'. When people view the post each time, the 'views' will be added 1. Now my step is

```
@post = Post.find_by_id(params[:id])
@post.views += 1
@post.save
```

Is there any better way to add 'views'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `increment` method:

```
@post.increment!(:views)
```

You can make it shorter

```
Post.find(params[:id]).try(:increment!,:views)
```

**Notice the use of `try` method cause a post record with that `id` might not exist.**

Comment: If it doesn't exist, the find will fail with an exception anyway

Comment: That's the idea of it, to avoid the exception.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your needs. If you just need to count views of the post, then I would just advise to move that line into a method in your model. If you need something more complex, you may have to introduce a model for a view, including the user that viewed the post, a timestamp of the view, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I second neutrino -- you should move that logic into a method inside the model. And probable use khelll's suggestion of using increment. Something like:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def increment_views
    self.increment!(:views)
  end
  ...
end
```

This way if you ever need to do more stuff then you need to change the model method only.